# for nested DOM elements, get all values for a certain attribute (e.g. all classes)

Tags: php, domdocument

Using `DOMDocument`, how do I get all classes of nested group of a DOMelement?

E.g. `$this->xmlComponent` that consists of:

```
<span class="one two"><a class="three" href="#">test</a></span>
```

Should result in `["one","two","three"]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DOMElement::getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getelementsbytagname.php) with parameter `*` to get all the child tags and then recursively iterate through all the children, getting the `class` attribute of each:

```
<?php
$html = '<span class="one two"><a class="three four" href="#"><b class="five">test</b></a></span>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$spans = $dom->getElementsByTagName("span");
$values = [];
foreach ($spans as $span) {
    $values[] = $span->getAttribute("class");
    $values[] = getAllValues($span);
}

function getAllValues($node)
{
    $values = [];
    $children = $node->getElementsByTagName('*');
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $values[] = $child->getAttribute("class");
        getAllValues($child);
    }
    return $values;
}

var_dump($values);
```

*Result:*

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'one two' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'three four' (length=10)
      1 => string 'five' (length=4)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/YXOZg)

And to get every class on its own element, simply `explode()` by an empty space:

```
foreach ($spans as $span) {
    $values[] = explode(" ", $span->getAttribute("class"));
    $values[] = getAllValues($span);
}

function getAllValues($node)
{
    $values = [];
    $children = $node->getElementsByTagName('*');
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $values[] = explode(" ", $child->getAttribute("class"));
        getAllValues($child);
    }
    return $values;
}
```

*Result*

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'one' (length=3)
      1 => string 'two' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'three' (length=5)
          1 => string 'four' (length=4)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'five' (length=4)
```

And lastly, to get everything in a flat array, pass `getAllValues()` the initial `$values` array by reference:

```
foreach ($spans as $span) {
    $values[] = explode(" ", $span->getAttribute("class"));
    getAllValues($span, $values);
}

function getAllValues($node, &$values)
{
    $children = $node->getElementsByTagName('*');
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $values[] = explode(" ", $child->getAttribute("class"));
        getAllValues($child, $values);
    }
    return $values;
}
```

*Result*

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'one' (length=3)
      1 => string 'two' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'three' (length=5)
      1 => string 'four' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'five' (length=4)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'five' (length=4)
```

And (sorry for the long post) as a final answer, since you mentioned you need a "certain" attribute, you can make this a function so you can get any attribute just by passing a parameter to the function (class by default), getting the array with all the values in return:

```
function getAllAttributesForNode($node, $attribute = "class")
{
    $values = [];
    foreach ($node as $child) {
        getAllValues($child, $values, $attribute);
    }

    return $values;
}

function getAllValues($node, &$values, $attribute)
{
    $values[] = explode(" ", $node->getAttribute($attribute));

    $children = $node->getElementsByTagName('*');
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        getAllValues($child, $values, $attribute);
    }

    return $values;
}

$spans = $dom->getElementsByTagName("span");
$values = getAllAttributesForNode($spans);
```

Comment: thanks ishegg for the thinking process and examples!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ishegg for the suggesting the approach.
Here is the condensed code I ended up using:

```
function getAllAttributes($nodes, $values, $attribute='class') {
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        $values = array_merge($values, explode(" ", $node->getAttribute($attribute)) );
        $children = $node->getElementsByTagName('*');
        $values = getAllAttributes($children, $values);
    }
    return $values; 
}

$html = '<span class="one two"><a class="three" href="#">test</a></span>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$spans = $dom->getElementsByTagName("span");

$classes = getAllAttributes($spans, []);
print_r($classes);
```